# R: grouping numbers into bins

Tags: r, grouping

I am looking to find the smallest number in a column in a data frame that is larger a number in another array.

Example
DistrDF

```
Bin Freq CumSum  
0.1 0.05 0.05  
0.2 0.07 0.12    
0.3 0.20 0.32  
0.4 0.10 0.42  
0.5 0.00 0.42   
0.6 0.15 0.57  
0.7 0.00 0.57  
0.8 0.30 0.87  
0.9 0.11 0.98  
1.0 0.02 1.0
```

Then I have an array of, say, 10 random numbers between 0 and 1 (i.e. each random number will fall into one of the bins in the DistrDF)

```
RandNums
0.13
0.50
0.11
0.10
0.70
0.05
0.12
0.80
0.88
0.40
```

I would like to use these two table to create a third table, which indicates into which bin each of the random numbers falls, as below:

```
ResultDF  
0.30 (because 0.13 < 0.32 and 0.13 > 0.12)
0.60 (because 0.50 < 0.57 and 0.50 > 0.42)
...
0.30 (because 0.40 < 0.42 and 0.40 > 0.32)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I feel like an `aggregate` or something might be in order, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cut` function does what you want:

```
DistrDF <- DistrDF[DistrDF$Freq > 0,]  # Remove empty bins
DistrDF$Bin[cut(x$RandNums, c(0, DistrDF$CumSum))]
# [1] 0.3 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.8 0.1 0.2 0.8 0.9 0.4
```

You can manipulate the `include.lowest` and `right` parameters to change how you handle points that fall on the border of bins.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am having difficulties implementing the solution, as I keep getting a "breaks are not unique" error. Any idea what may be causing that? Thanks again!

Comment: never mind, I missed the first line wherein you deleted empty bins. Although I don't understand why an empty bin causes it to fail? Thanks again!